# How does torch differentiate between batch and single values?

Tags: pytorch

Here’s my neural network.

```
from torch import nn
from torch.utils.data import DataLoader
class NeuralNetwork(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, state_size, action_size):
        super(NeuralNetwork, self).__init__()
        self.state_size = state_size
        self.action_size = action_size
#         self.flatten = nn.Flatten()
        self.linear_relu_stack = nn.Sequential(
            nn.Linear(1, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, 30),
            nn.ReLU(),
            nn.Linear(30, action_size)
        )
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.linear_relu_stack(x)
        return x
```

As you can imagine, it can compute tensor inputs of the shape torch.Size([1]). However, when I try to feed it batch data, for instance, shape torch.Size([10]) it throws the following error -

```
RuntimeError: mat1 and mat2 shapes cannot be multiplied (1x10 and 1x30)
```

For instance, this code works -

```
net = NeuralNetwork(10, 5)
x1 = torch.rand(1)
print(x1.shape)
out = net(x1)
```

But this fails -

```
x2 = torch.rand(10)
print(x2.shape)
out = net(x2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to change your inputs a little bit. Your code is expecting the `net()` to have a second dimension of 1, so it can multiply by `nn.linear(1,30)`.  The inner dimensions must match for matrix multiplication to occur.  I.e. 10x1 * 1x30:

```
x2 = torch.rand(10,1)
print(x2.shape)
out = net(x2)
torch.Size([10, 1])
```

Try this with any dimension `x2 = torch.rand(100,1)` etc. it still works.